# angular js controller add remove() function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to add a remove() function to my controller in angular js to where when the button is clicked, it removes that particular customer. Here is my codes:

```
    <script>
//create an object that ties with module
// pass an array of dependencies
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []); 
//create controller
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.customers = []; 
    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
        $scope.date = new Date();
        $scope.customers.push({
        name: $scope.customer.name

    })  
}


})

</script>
```

Comment: good luck, where's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give any details about your application, but here is one way to implement a `remove()` function:

```
$scope.removeCustomer = function(index){
    $scope.customers.splice(index,1);
}
```

Assuming you had a table in a view that displayed the customers, you would bind a button in each row to `removeCustomer`, passing in the `$index`:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in customers">
      <td>{{c.name}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click='removeCustomer($index)'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3w1BgZXNTIBhAWjKbJtD?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Jerrad, that was really helpful. I am a totally new angular.